# Remove element from array by type

Tags: ruby

I have the following array:

```
["--",1,2,3,4]
```

How can I remove elements from the array by element type, ie. remove all non-integer values from the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do :-

```
ary = ["--",1,2,3,4]
ary = ary.grep(Integer) 
ary # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

*Note* :- If you don't want to mutate the original array use `new_ary` instead of `ary`. Like

```
new_ary = ary.grep(Integer)
```

Comment: +1 - do you need the intersection in `ary = ary & ...` ?

Comment: Thanks, at first I thought it didn't work, then I realized that my array is all strings- ["--","1","2"]. Now I need to find a way to drop an element if it cannot be converted into Integer.

Comment: @user3385895 then `ary.select do |s|
  begin
    Integer s
  rescue ArgumentError
    false
  end
end` --- Read `Kernel#Integer`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `delete_if` to remove items from the list, however this modifies the list.

```
a = ["--", 1, 2, 3, 4]
a.delete_if { |n| !n.kind_of?(Fixnum) }
p a
```

You can select items out of the list maintaining the original list by using `select`

```
a = ["--", 1, 2, 3, 4]
b = a.select { |n| n.kind_of?(Fixnum) }
p b
p a
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution addresses the title, rather than the example, and permits the selection of elements by class, as well as the rejection of elements by class.

**Code**

`good_classes` and `bad_classes` are arrays of classes.

```
def filter_select(arr, *good_classes)
  arr.select { |e| good_classes.include? e.class }
end

def filter_reject(arr, *bad_classes)
  arr.reject { |e| bad_classes.include? e.class }
end
```

**Examples**

```
arr = [1, :a, {b: 3}, "cat", [4,5], true, 3..4, false]

filter_select(arr, Fixnum, Hash, TrueClass, Range)
  #=> [1, {:b=>3}, true, 3..4]

filter_reject(arr, Fixnum, Hash, String, Array)
  #=> [:a, true, 3..4, false]
```

Comment: I would make the `good_classes` and `bad_classes` splats for one major reason: Avoiding calls with a second argument of `[Fixnum]`. The method bodies would be unchanged.

Comment: Thanks, @izuriel.  I prefer having individual arguments rather than an array as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do
`new_array = ary.reject {|x| x.is_a?(String)}`